# Best approach to log changes upon PUT

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm doing a REST Service (using the amazing [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack), though it's not relevant for the question) and I now need to log changed that happen upon `PUT` request.

currently my update approach is as:

```
public object Put(PostActivityInformation request)
{
    var session = this.SessionAs<MyCustomApiAuthSession>();

    var activity = _activitiesRepository.GetActivityById(_companyRepository, session.CurrentCompany.Guid, request.Id);

    if (_activitiesRepository.IsActivityDuplicated(session.CurrentCompany.Id, request.SmsCode, request.Name, request.Id))
        return HttpError.Conflict("Found a duplicated activity");

    // update what is passed
    activity.Category = request.Category ?? activity.Category;
    activity.Description = request.Description ?? activity.Description;
    activity.ExtraTextDescription = request.ExtraTextDescription ?? activity.ExtraTextDescription;
    activity.Name = request.Name ?? activity.Name;
    activity.Points = request.Points ?? activity.Points;
    activity.SaveExtraText = request.SaveExtraText ?? activity.SaveExtraText;
    activity.SmsCode = request.SmsCode ?? activity.SmsCode;

    activity.IsActive = request.Active ?? activity.IsActive;
    activity.IsArchived = request.Archived ?? activity.IsArchived;

    // update stamp
    activity.UpdatedTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    activity.UpdatedUser = session.CurrentUser.Id;

    // save
    _activitiesRepository.SaveOrUpdate(activity);

    // log
    session.AddLog("Activity updated: {0}".Fmt(activity.Name), LogArea.Activities, activity.Id);

    return activity.ToActivityResponse();
}
```

But I would like to be more descriptive and also save the changes, something like replacing

```
activity.Category = request.Category ?? activity.Category;
activity.Description = request.Description ?? activity.Description;
```

by

```
var log = new StringBuilder();
if (request.Category != null)
{
    log.AppendFormat("Category changed from '{0}' to '{1}'", activity.Category, request.Category);
    activity.Category = request.Category;
}
if (request.Description != null)
{
    log.AppendFormat("Description changed from '{0}' to '{1}'", activity.Description, request.Description);
    activity.Description = request.Description;
}
```

and then save the `log` variable into my audit table...

What should be the best approach, as I do have several updates in the API, not only the "activities"?

I was thinking about an **ExtensionMethod**, but that will use *Refection* and will slower things a bit...

Did any of you already passed though this question, what did you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach it to format the log as you change settings using a pair of helper methods:

```
private static void T? Update(T? newVal, T? oldVal, string name, StringBuilder log) where T : struct {
    if (!Equals(newVal, oldVal)) {
        log.AppendFormat("{0} changed from '{1}' to '{2}'", name, oldVal, newVal);
    }
    return newVal ?? oldVal;
}
private static void T Update(T newVal, T oldVal, string name, StringBuilder log) where T : class {
    if (!Equals(newVal, oldVal)) {
        log.AppendFormat("{0} changed from '{1}' to '{2}'", name, oldVal, newVal);
    }
    return newVal ?? oldVal;
}
```

Now you can unify your code as follows:

```
activity.Category = Update(request.Category, activity.Category, nameof(activity.Category), log);
activity.Description = Update(request.Description, activity.Description, nameof(activity.Description), log);
activity.ExtraTextDescription = Update(request.ExtraTextDescription, activity.ExtraTextDescription, nameof(activity.ExtraTextDescription), log);
...
```

**Note:** I assume that you do not have much flexibility at changing the architecture at this point, but a good alternative approach to keeping an audit is letting the audit be your primary source of information on what has changed. Of course this transforms the audit log from a list of formatted strings to a full-blown registry of objects. See [*Event Sourcing Pattern*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn589792.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I'm actually in the process of even designing the database, so I just need a bit more read on the ES Pattern, Thank you!

Comment: but wait... I will not have a "classic" relational data store... and will take much more time to accomplish such process :( I will take the EXtMethods road for now, but will look in deep into the ES Pattern! for everyone out there, as I am, not knowing exactly how to do ES, check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5FPkCgcH4M) to start.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement something similar to INotifyPropertyChanged in your Activity class, where in the event data you would have the property name, the old value and the new value.